# Solaris cp -P not setting directory ownership when there is a soft link

Tags: solaris-10

I've encountered an oddity when doing a copy in Solaris 10 update 10 (sparc, 147440-25).

Here is the setup (done as root):

```
# cd /tmp
# mkdir foo
# touch foo/thing1
# ln -s thing1 foo/thing2
# chown -hR joe:user foo
```

If you look at the directory and the link, everything is owned by the user "joe".  Now comes the interesting part:

```
# cp -rpP foo bar
```

The options to cp here are to recurse, preserve permissions and ownership, and to act on links instead of following them.  But when I do this, while the link is copied with the correct permissions, the directory itself, bar, is set to root:root.  Is there some reason for this behavior?

It only acts this way if there is a link in the directory.  If the directory contains only files all ownership is preserved (I assume because the -P never comes into play).

Comment: Are you just bothered by the cosmetic issue or are you concerned by something else ? AFAIK, owner/group and file permissions set on a symbolic link are never used/enforced.

Comment: Sorry, I stopped watching this thread a while back.  It's not a cosmetic issue.  The ownership of the link is fine.  It's the ownership of the parent directory that's not getting preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed an odd `cp` behavior I reproduced on the same Solaris release.

Not sure there is a patch for Solaris 10 but the issue is fixed in Solaris 11.1.